# Terraform GCP unable to run metadata command for windows instance to create a user

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Trying to create a user which can be used in connection to move some files , when i try to create a user while creating a instance using metadata resource get created successfully but metadata command is not executed.

```
`resource "google_compute_instance" "win-dev-instance" {
 project = "my_pro_1"
 zone = "eu-west2-b"
 name = "win-dev-instance"
 machine_type = "f1-micro"
 boot_disk {
   initialize_params {
     image = "windows-server-2016-r2-dc-v20191210"
   }
 }
 network_interface {
   network = "default"
   access_config {
   }
 }
 metadata {
    windows-startup-script-cmd = "net user /add devuser PASSWORD & net localgroup adminstrators devuser /add"
  }
}`
```

Comment: How do you know the command is not being executed?  Are there any message logs?  Have you looked at the serial port startup of the compute engine?  If you create the compute engine instance from the Console and not using Terraform, does it work then/there?

Comment: Thank you for providing that, works well!

Answer (score 5):

In your example, there is a typo `adminstrators`, it should be `administrators`.

**Solution**

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "win-dev-instance" {
  project      = "my_pro_1"
  zone         = "eu-west2-b"
  name         = "win-dev-instance"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "windows-server-2016-dc-v20191210"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
  }
  metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-cmd = "net user /add devuser Abc123123 & net localgroup administrators devuser /add"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test without success the solution based on `windows-startup-script-cmd`. Also this script will be excuted every time the instance restart.
I think the best solution is to use the metadata with the `windows-keys` key as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation?hl=fr#manual_instructions). The solution is to generate a double key, one will be used by gcp to generate the password and the second to decrypt it on reception